# Sass @function which returns prefixed or suffixed list

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm trying to write a sass `@function function_name($prefix, $list_of_values)`
which will return  a list of values, where each value from `$list_of_values` will be prefixed with `$prefix` and suffixed with comma, except the last one. Possibly it already exist in sass or compass and I just don't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of writing it:

```
@function prefixer($prefix, $list) {
    $new-list: ();
    @for $i from 1 to length($list) {
        $new-list: append($new-list, $prefix + nth($list, $i), comma);
    }
    $new-list: append($new-list, nth($list, length($list), comma));
}
```